# Azure http trigger is not allowing to create a folder in python using makedirs

Tags: python, azure, azure-http-trigger

I am trying to create a new folder inside of Azure http trigger folder, in order to receive some files from an API call and save them based on the name.

```
config_country_folder = context.function_directory+"/config/"+country.upper()
os.makedirs(config_country_folder, exist_ok=True)
logging.info('Config folder was added')
```

this part is inside the `__init__.py` of the trigger, and it's working locally.

however, once deployed and tested, the following error of code 500 occurred:

> Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 38] Function not
> implemented: '/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTrigger1/config' Stack: File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 452, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await
> self._loop.run_in_executor( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in
> run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 718, in _run_sync_func return
> ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py",
> line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTrigger1/**init**.py", line 33, in main
> os.makedirs(config_country_folder, exist_ok=True) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs makedirs(head,
> exist_ok=exist_ok) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in
> makedirs mkdir(name, mode)

The issue is over the makedirs, and I went through the web, which they advised on using the context of the function to create folders. however the error occurred.

Also I was checking this link on using [tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955013/error-in-azure-functions-for-python-whenever-trying-to-create-new-directory) library, but this is not what I need here.

Comment: You have referred to that SO answer already, and still want to `create` a 'folder' !?

Comment: yes, we don't work with files as much as we work with folder structure for migration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Create an azure Http trigger function in vs code. You can follow the below process.

Creating  Httptrigger:
We can create in our local with the python environment
and select Http trigger
[image]

Now go to **init**.py file and replace the code below to create a new folder
Code:

```
import  os

def  main(req):
local_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
function_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(local_path, ".."))
local_folder_path = os.path.join(local_path, "new_folder")
os.makedirs(local_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
function_folder_path = os.path.join(function_path, "new_folder")
os.makedirs(function_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
return  f"Created folders at {local_folder_path} and {function_folder_path}"
```

It worked in my local environment first.

And, Then deployed in azure function app.

[image]

This is my output from the above steps.

[image]